# DLL is loaded twice using LoadLibrary

Tags: windows, winapi

I have `A.DLL` and `B.DLL`

Using VS 2010, I set a breakpoint in a C++ function in `A.DLL` project and use *procexp.exe* to see what DLLs are currently loaded. Obviously, `A.DLL` is loaded.

I need to call `B.DLL` from this function. Note: `B.DLL` has a library dependency on `A.DLL`. This library is called `A.LIB`

Using `LoadLibrary`, I execute the statement:

```
HANDLE hLib = LoadLibrary("B.DLL");
```

After this line is executed, I look at *procexp.exe* again. `A.DLL` is loaded twice!! If I remove the `A.LIB` dependency on `B.DLL`, this won't happen. Process Explorer reports that the two instances of `A.DLL` have different base addresses so they really are different modules.

My question is why does this load another instance of `A.DLL`? Is it possible for it to realize `A.DLL` is already loaded?

Comment: Are they the *same* `A.DLL`?  Are you sure you're not loading two different `A.DLL`s from different file paths?

Comment: procexp shows they are from the same file path, same version, and same time stamp. It's literally creating the same DLL twice for some reason

Comment: The second instance of `A.DLL` loads when you call `LoadLibrary("B.DLL");` Take a look at the PE import table for `B.DLL`. Use dumpbin for that. Make a note of the exact name used to specify `A.DLL`. Then do the same for the host exe which has a dependency on `A.DLL`. Is it the same? I trust you use the same `A.LIB` file when you build host exe and `B.DLL`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: what dumpbin command line option is that? /IMPORTS? (never used it before)

Comment: Yes, I think that's the one

Answer (score 0):

So I could not figure out the reasoning behind why `A.DLL` was loaded twice, so I went ahead and restructured my code and came up with a better solution. (which ended up working fine for me)

Instead of `B.DLL` having a library dependency on `A.DLL`, I removed that dependency and instead of having some exportable function that was exposed through `A.LIB`, I used a `function pointer` for this function and passed it down through my call to LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress, and so on.

In doing so, it does not load `A.DLL` twice and all is good now :)